# Download JSON File and save in internal storage (Android/Kotlin)

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I've a simple JSON-File and I want to download the file and save it in the **internal** storage. My function can download files, but I can't save it in the internal storage:

```
val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("Some_URL"))
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
        request.setTitle("Download")
        request.setDescription("File is downloading...")
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner()
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "FILE_NAME")

        val manager = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
        manager.enqueue(request)
```

I tried after the download to copy the file and save it in the internal storage like that:

```
val file = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
            "FILE_NAME")

val result = file.readText()
this.openFileOutput("FILE_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).use {
            it.write(result.toByteArray())
}
```

It works, but I don't like it. The way how I did it, is really bad.

Answer (score 1):

Use preferences:

```
private void saveJson(Context context, String json) {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("json", json).apply();
}

private String loadJson(Context context){
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString("json", "");
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: So, I download the file via DownloadManager and save the content of this file in preferences?

Comment: @jamesxbrown yes, its simplest way and that should be enough. With your solution there is lot of edge cases you would have to handle. Also other applications have no access to your private app shared preferences. Only in case they have rooted phone.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little bit confused. When I use DownloadManager, the file is already saved in the external storage, isn't? So it makes no difference when I copy the content of the file in preferences or as a new file. Or did I understand something incorrectly?

Comment: Read your file, save json string in your app preferences, delete downloaded file